# Hotel wifi terms agreement page won't load

Tags: wireless-networking

I am connected to the internet but the terms agreement page wont load. I tried typing in an adress, still a blank page. I changed my internet settings to DHCP. I turned off my proxy setting, but still a blank page.

Comment: Make sure you aren't trying to load a page that is secure. That often won't trigger the terms agreement page loading. If necessary, manually select a URL you've never been to, like `http://example.com` (literally).

Comment: ALso, some access pages like only IE for some reason... Blank page may indicate display problems related to page configuration, which are handled differently by different browsers.

Comment: Welcome at SuperUser, your question does not provide enough information to help you. What addresses did you try? Does you laptop/smart phone has the same problem? What did they tell you when you asked about this problem at hotel reception desk?

Answer (score -1):

I have that issue often, but as those pages are notoriously slow and malfunctioning, consider the issue might not be on your end.

1. As David already commented, make sure to try to load a non-https site that you never had before (or that doesn't support https; like 'cnn.com'). Using for example google.com does *not* work, as it gets implicitly converted to http**s**://www.google.com
2. In some nasty cases, I did this in two steps: Use another device ('B'), connect, and get the IP address. Go to the device that makes problems ('A'), and hard assign it that IP address. Switch off Wifi for the other device ('B'). First device ('A') works now. Not elegant, but got me in.

I understand that this is not a full answer, but probably there is none (and I am not allowed to comment)

Comment: What would make it a fuller answer would be to say why these things work. For example - the fact that https wouldn't connect via the captive portal for security reasons, and you want a site you've never been to because of caching

Answer (score -2):

I had this issue since I statically assigned my DNS server to Cloudflare's 1.1.1.1. I removed my static DNS server config and then my DNS server was configured to use the hotel's router.

This enabled the hotel wifi agreement page to resolve. After accepting the agreement, I restored my DNS server back to 1.1.1.1.